# How do I create a function that will target a certain class in a link and generate a popup window for that link?

Tags: php, javascript

I am not sure how I'd do this but I want to create a function that will allow a link to generate a pop up window. These links I'm guessing would need to be targeted with a special class which can be manually inserted.

For example, `<a class="popup" href="http://mysite.com"></a>`

I haven't created a popup in a long time so I am at a loss as to where to begin. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: stackoverflow members will not code for you, there gonna solve your problems. Therefore you should. 1. Try your self first 2. if it still does not work, ask for a specific problem you encounter during your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use JQuery

`$('.popup').click(function() { alert('popup!!!'); return false; }`

Use a framework like lightbox or JQuery Tools to get a prettier popup.